# How do I configure networking on CentOS 6 running on hyper-v?

Tags: linux, centos, virtualization, hyper-v

I'm not using legacy adapters, and i've installed Linux Integration Components 3.2.

THe problem i'm facing is that the command 'setup' or 'system-config-network' doesn't list any network interfaces. If i run ifconfig -a i can see both the network cards i've attached. By setting a ip using ifconfig i can get network connectivity. The problem is that it's not persistent after a reboot.

I'm a 100% centos newbie, but I figure it has something to do with that the centos installer couldn't see the NICs on install.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` there should be a line that says `ONBOOT=yes` which causes eth0 to be configured when the system starts.

Comment: There's no such file. But creating it with Device=eth0 and restarting /etc/init.d/network made it visible for system-config-network so now it's working :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case once I added the integration services I went in and created the ifcfg-eth0 file with the following

DEVICE=eth0
 BOOTPROTO=dhcp
 HWADDR=(fill in yours)
 ONBOOT=yes

then I ran system-config-network and added my DNS servers (this may not have been necessary)

once I did that and restarted the network service it started responding to CentOS 6.3 .

This was under HyperV built into Windows 8 Enterprise

Answer (score 1):

Adding to lain's answer..

I'm running Hyper-V, CentOS 6.2.

1. When initially setting up your VM for CentOS, do the "delete the network adapter...add a legacy adapter" like everyone says.
2. AFTER that, install CentOS
3. Upon first boot, run system-config-network.  You should see eth0.  Edit it.
4. eth0 should show it is set to DHCP ... [*].  I changed my to static.
5. cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts
6. ifup eth0     (run it)...it should take a moment while the interface initializes
7. Try to ping your gateway.
8. Follow lain's instructions to get your eth0 to start at boot.

Answer (score 0):

CentOS (like almost all modern *nix OSes) uses a [set of configuration scripts](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/s1-networkscripts-files.html) at startup to configure various parts of the system including network configuration scripts/files.

You can [manually edit the relevant file to configure](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html) each of the synthetic NICs when the system boots.

Answer (score 0):

The trick seems to be to run the command 'system-config-network' at a shell prompt as root after you've installed the Linux Integration Services. On my CentOS 6.2 instance it detected the virtual network adapter and after I saved my configuration changes and did a reboot I was on the road.